# JavaScript showing active div when scroll the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I searched almost everywhere but I couldn't find it. I have a feed like facebook or instagram. I put the advirtesment div after every 5 posts like other posts(like on instagram). The problem is that when I scroll the page if scroll position is at the advirtesment div I want to add a class like in-view with js. How can I do that? By the way, I load other posts when scroll is bottom of page.
Thank you in advance

Comment: it might help http://jsfiddle.net/U4qyp/32/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery getBoundingClientRect to check if element is in view and then add in-view class to it. Pass your div element to following method and it will return true if your div is in viewport

```
function isElementInView(element){
  var boundry = element.getBoundingClientRect();

  var isInView = boundry.top >= 0 && boundry.left >= 0 &&  
                 boundry.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || $(window).height()) &&  
                 boundry.right <= (window.innerWidth || $(window).width());

  return isInView;
}
```